# Get average of the difference in datetime columns?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an `Item` class

```
public class Item {
    //...
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

In a method, I have `List<Item> items`. How would I query average of date differences in days more succinctly than looping through the list?

```
double days = 0;
int total = 0;

foreach (var @t in results)
{
    if (@t.EndDate != null)
    {
        total++;
        TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)(@t.EndDate - @t.CreateDate);
        days = ts.TotalDays;
    }
}

double avg = days / total;
```

Comment: What's the **results** ?

Comment: What's the type of `var`? It doesn't look like it's `Item`.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - If `results` is of type `List<Item>`, then each instance of `@t` must be of type `Item`.

Comment: @Thomas: I understand that, but `CreateDate` and `EndDate` are not properties of `Item`.

Comment: That's my mistake. They should be the same properties from `Item`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var avg = results.Average( x => (x.EndDate - x.CreateDate).TotalDays );
```

Version that filters out null `EndDate` values and assuming that CreateDate is not of type `DateTime?`:

```
var avg = results.Where( x=> x.EndDate.HasValue)
    .Average( x => (x.EndDate.Value - x.CreateDate).TotalDays );
```

#### Edit

It was asked out to format the duration in the format of `dd:HH:ss`. To do that, we should average the total milliseconds (or seconds) and do something like:

```
var avg = results.Where(x=> x.EndDate.HasValue && x.CreateDate.HasValue)
    .Average( x => (x.EndDate.Value - x.CreateDate.Value).TotalMilliseconds );
var fancyOutput = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( avg );
Response.Write( fancyOutput.ToString() );
```

[TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx)

Comment: Instead of `.TotalDays`, how would I format that as a string, `"dd\:hh\:ss"` instead? I tried `ToString` with that format, but it throws an error -- cannot implicitly convert `string` to `decimal?` (nullable). Note: I had to use `x.EndDate.Value - x.CreateDate.Value` since those values are also nullable.

Comment: @Josh - Done. In essence, you need to convert the total milliseconds or seconds to a `TimeSpan` instance and then output the format you want.

Comment: That's the solution I came to as well! Thank you!